# Integrating Magento with Adempiere

Tags: magento, adempiere

We have a client who wants to track all the sales in Magento into Adempiere.How to integrate Magento with Adempiere? Are there any APIs by which we can get integration done?

Comment: you could use an ETL tool like `Kettle` to enable communications between adempiere and magneto through flat files, or you could use `Apache ActiveMQ` for the communication and rather send xml files.

Comment: See this http://testadempiere.com/adaxa-magento-connector/

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option could be; Adempiere comes with a basic webstore - not many use it but utilises a suite of servlets that provide all the functionality you need to create orders or extract data re customers, products & pricing.  You'll find the code in the ServerApps.

There is a chapter in the packt publishing book "Adempiere Cookbook" that describes integration with Joomla's VirtueMart which, I imagine, you could use just as easily for Magento. They use the ActiveMQ approach but they don't use the existing functionality for creating processing messages that exists in the "Replication" feature but rather recreate this JMS integration on the adempiere side.

Replication is intended for use between Adempiere instances but I believe it could be used for any JMS communications. MOre [here](http://www.adempiere.com/Sponsored_Development:_Replication) and [here](http://www.adempiere.com/Replication_HowTo)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Apache camel and Apache rabbit mq. We have already did this using web services.

We used Apache camel for redirecting services and used rabbit mq for service queuing.